# CSV file not reloading (Google GeoCharts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-visualization, jquery-csv

I am loading csv file using https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv. Everything works okay until I try to reload the .csv file and load new data into GeoCharts. I know its a problem with reloading the file but how to deal with it? Here is the example code:

```
function load(file, colorForSex){

    var region = $('select[name="region"] option:selected').val();

    setTimeout(1000);

    $.get(file, function(data) {

        var newData = $.csv.toArrays(data);

        var j = 1;

        for (var i = 1; i < newData.length; i++) {
           newData[i][j] = parseFloat(newData[i][j]);
        }

    }, 'text');

    console.log(newData[1][1]);


    setTimeout(1000);

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(newData);

    var options = {
        region: region,
        backgroundColor: 'none',
        chartArea: { width: '100%', height: '100%' },
        colorAxis: {colors: ['#ddd', colorForSex]},
        datalessRegionColor: 'white',
        legend: {
            numberFormat: '.##',
            textStyle: {
                fontName: 'Verdana',
                color: '#ff1a1a',
                fontSize: 14
            }
        }   
    };

    setTimeout(1000);


    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two calls to [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)? If you're using it to stop code from executing temporarily, I don't think it does that.

Comment: I thought it was a loading error or sth.

Answer (score 1):

need to include the rest of the chart code in the `$.get` function

`$.get` is *asynchronous*

as such, the code **after** the `$.get` function **runs before** the `$.get` function finishes

see following snippet...

```
function loadData(file, colorForSex){
  var region = $('select[name="region"] option:selected').val();
  var file = file + '?q=' + Math.random();
  $.get(file, function(data) {
    var processedData = $.csv.toArrays(data);
    var j = 1;
    for (var i = 1; i < processedData.length; i++) {
      processedData[i][j] = parseFloat(processedData[i][j]);
    }

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(processedData);

    var options = {
      region: region,
      backgroundColor: 'none',
      chartArea: { width: '100%', height: '100%' },
      colorAxis: {colors: ['#ddd', colorForSex]},
      datalessRegionColor: 'white',
      legend: {
        numberFormat: '.##',
        textStyle: {
            fontName: 'Verdana',
            color: '#ff1a1a',
            fontSize: 14
        }
      }   
    };

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }, 'text');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add to file some parameter to cache disable

replace:
`$.get(file, function(data) {`

to:
`var d = new Date();
$.get(file + '?' + d.getTime(), function(data) {`